# AlphaPose on Opencv GPU with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, documentation, opencv

I am trying to speed up my ALphaPose algorithm by using OpenCV GPU with python. It seems pretty hard to find any documention on the functions allowed on OpencvGPU. I was wondering if any of you managed to use well this library and if you had any tips or help to give me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps see https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/. Type something in the search field. I believe that nything for GPU would be listed as cv::cud

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. However I already checked this doc and everything is in C++. Do you know if there are any existing documentation or website that refer to the functions usable with Python?
Thx

Comment: No, I do not know. Sorry.